# Momentum in terms of comoving velocity in cosmology

Tags: fluid-dynamics, cosmology, momentum, space-expansion

I want to understand why the following relation holds in the context of Cosmology, considering that $m$ is the mass of a particle of the fluid that fills the universe:

$$\vec{p}=am\vec{u}$$

where this is the notation used:

- $\vec{x}$ is the vector of comoving coordinates.
- $\vec{r}=a\vec{x}$ is the vector of physical coordinates.
- $\vec{p}$ is called the canonical momentum.
- $u=\vec{x'}=d\vec{x}/d\tau$ is the comoving velocity.
- $d\tau=dt/a$ defines conformal time $\tau$ in terms of physical time $t$, which means that $d/dt=(1/a)d/d\tau$.

My attempt at understanding this equation is the following:

$$\vec{p}=m\dfrac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=m\dfrac{d(a\vec{x})}{dt}=m\bigg(\dfrac{da}{dt}\vec{x}+a\dfrac{d\vec{x}}{dt}\bigg)=m\bigg(\dfrac{1}{a}\dfrac{da}{d\tau}\vec{x}+a\dfrac{1}{a}\dfrac{d\vec{x}}{d\tau}\bigg)=m(\mathcal{H}\vec{x}+\vec{x'})$$

This is not the result I want to get. Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance!

**Edit:** I believe that $\vec{p}$ here might be related to the canonical momentum in Classical Mechanics (they could even be the same concept?), but in that case, which Lagrangian should I use to compute it?